# Plot in solid temperature

Tags: plotting, functions, mathematical-optimization

Given the function *f : R^3 -> R* defined by:

*f(x, y, z) := x e^(y^2 + z^2)*

you will determine the points of maximum and minimum for f constrained to:

*D := { (x, y, z) \in R^3 : 0 <= x <= 1 - y^2 - z^2 }.*

Now, analytically is all very simple, however, since f is not possible to draw the graph (need one 4-dimensional space) I thought to consider f as a function that at every point in 3D space associated with a temperature represented by a graduated scale colors.

I was wondering if someone could point a way to plot D in Wolfram Mathematica coloring each own point according to the function f, so you can find the minimum and the absolute maximum by colors.

Thank you!

---

I thought *DensityPlot3D*, but I think in Wolfram Mathematica 11.0 there is a problem:

[image]

and the same happens to me in the main window.

To you it does not happen on *Windows 8.1, 64 bits*? :(

---

Through code:

```
A = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 - y^2 - z^2, {x, y, z}];
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 x E^(y^2 + z^2), {x == 0, x == 1 - y^2 - z^2}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  A, AxesLabel -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I get:

[image]

which is almost what I want. How do I delete those nasty "holes"?

Comment: Have you seen `DensityPlot3D[]`?

Comment: Then, please also include the OS you are using.

Comment: If `DensityPlot3D[]` does not work for you because of bugs, you could consider using `SliceContourPlot3D[]`  - at example: `SliceContourPlot3D[
 x*Exp[y^2 + z^2], {"YStackedPlanes", 10}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 - y^2 - z^2, {x, y, z}]]`

Comment: Have you tried disable anti-aliasing?

Comment: I meant, disable it in the preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)

```
RegionPlot3D[
 0 <= x <= 1 - y^2 - z^2 && -1 <= y <= 1 && -1 <= z <= 1,
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
   ColorData["Rainbow"][x E^(y^2 + z^2)]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 MeshFunctions ->
  Function[{x, y, z}, x E^(y^2 + z^2)],
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

[image]